# how to add a sum of even and odd number of an array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i am trying to get the sum of even numbers from a recursive array and the sum of an odd number and then add both sums together. i am trying to loop through the arrays so that to get the even numbers but it keep return the first index. please help and thanks in advance..

my aim is to take in array 2,1,5,9,8,4 take the even index and add it to the odd indexes. a[0]=2,a[1]=1,a[2]=5, a[3]=9, a[4]=8, a[5]=4. so it would take (2+5+8)-(1+9+4)=1

this is what i got so far i am not familiar with recursive so my code might be off

```
int calc(int *a, int size)
{
    if(size==1 || size==0)
        return a[0];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        if(i%2==0){
            int sum_i = a[i];
            int m=calc(a, size-1);
            if(m>a[size-1])
                return m;
        }
    }
    for(int j=0; j<size; j++){
        if(j%2!=0);
        int sum_j = a[j];
        return sum_j;
    }
    int sum = a[i] - a[j];
    int e = calc(a, size-1);
    if(e%2==0)
        return e=e+0; //return even

    return sum;
}

int main( )
{
    int a[6]={1,2,3,5,6,2};
    int size = 6;   
    cout<< calc(a, size)<<endl;

    system("pause");   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you looping over the array twice?  When you determine if the array element is even or odd, use your logic to add the number to the correct sum value.  This is particularly important for large arrays when you don't want to be looping any more than you have to.

Comment: What is your intent with the statement `if(j%2!=0);`? What do you expect this to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need recursion for this?

```
// calc(): returns sum(a[0], a[2], a[4], ...) - sum(a[1], a[3], a[5], ...)
int calc(int *a, int size)
{
    int sum_even_pos = 0;
    int sum_odd_pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        sum_even_pos += a[i];
        if (++i < size) sum_odd_pos += a[i];
    }
    return sum_even_pos - sum_odd_pos;
}
```

http://codepad.org/DVx0sgg1

Comment: Shouldn't the output in your link be -1? `1 + 3 + 5 = 9`, `2 + 6 + 2 = 10`, `9 - 10 = -1`.

Comment: Nope. `1 + 3 + 6 = 10`, `2 + 5 + 2 = 9`, `10 - 9 = 1`

Comment: since when is 6 an odd number? and since when is 5 an even number? I see now that this is supposed to be the sum of the even and odd indexes, but your variable names didn't reflect that.

Comment: You're right. Once again my big mistake was coding before coffee :/

Comment: this points me in the right direction, so i have to make it recursive for practical purpose.